# Layering an image but with a link

Tags: html, image

I am trying to layer 2 images one on top of each other but the second image that is on top is also a link.

Here is the working code for it:

```
<div style="position: relative; left: 0; top: 0;">
  <img src="http://www.handicappedpets.com/images/newproducts/fabricharnessweb.jpg" style="position: relative; top: 0; left: 0;"/>
  <a href="http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.handicappedpets.com%2Findex.php%2Fwalkin-wheels-rear-harness.html&media=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.handicappedpets.com%2Fimages%2Fnewproducts%2Ffabricharnessweb.jpg&description=The%20Walkin'%20Wheels%20Rear%20Harness%20is%20used%20to%20support%20your%20dogs%20hind%20quarters.%20Starting%20at%20%2439.99" class="pin-it-button" count-layout="horizontal"><img border="0" src="//assets.pinterest.com/images/PinExt.png" title="Pin It" style="position: absolute; top: 425px; left: 20px;" /></a>
</div>
```

(Or you can click here) http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/nFvUu/3/

But if i throw this code into a real website..
http://www.handicappedpets.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=819
It push's the image off to the side instead of on top of each other.

Any ideas of why it does this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out:

```
    <div style="position: relative; left: 0; top: 0; z-index:1;">
  <img style="position: relative; top: 0; left: 0; z-index:2;" title="wizard new var 2" alt="wizard new var 2" src="http://www.handicappedpets.com/images/newproducts/fabricharnessweb.jpg">
<div style="position: absolute; top: 425px; left: 20px;  z-index:3;">
  <a href="http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.handicappedpets.com%2Findex.php%2Fwalkin-wheels-rear-harness.html&amp;media=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.handicappedpets.com%2Fimages%2Fnewproducts%2Ffabricharnessweb.jpg&amp;description=The%20Walkin%27%20Wheels%20Rear%20Harness%20is%20used%20to%20support%20your%20dogs%20hind%20quarters.%20Starting%20at%20%2439.99" data-pin-aha="button_pinit" data-pin-config="beside" class="PIN_1358884071645_pin_it_button PIN_1358884071645_pin_it_beside"><span class="PIN_1358884071645_pin_it_button_count" id="PIN_1358884071645_pin_count_1"><i></i>1</span></a>
</div>
</div>
```

You most likely just needed z-indexes. Seems to work fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/nFvUu/4/

**EDIT**

Pinterest was overwriting the 3rd setting.  Use the above, wraps the pinterest in an additional div and places it where you need it.  Worked in firebug on your site.

Comment: I put that into my site...seems to be doing the same thing. :(

Comment: May want to get that out of inline styling and into your css file at some point.  Cleaner, "correct", and re-useable that way.

Comment: Most welcome.  Have made another fiddle for you http://jsfiddle.net/nFvUu/6/ .   This seperates it and gets it out of that inline css for you.  You can also reuse the formula for other pages this way.